# Will I still get all emails in a thread if I set up automatic reply?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

If I set up an automatic reply in Outlook, my understanding is that the sender will only receive the auto reply once. If they send me additional messages on the same thread, will those still go through to my email? Just wondering because I set up an automatic reply last week and have not heard back from a few people I expected to hear from on existing email chains. So I just want to make sure that if they send a follow up email that I will still receive it — I hope that makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

You get all the emails that have been sent to you. This is independent of Automatic Reply (which, yes, happens once or we would drown in auto replies).

> I set up an automatic reply last week and have not heard back from a
> few people I expected to hear from on existing email chains. So I just
> want to make sure that if they send a follow up email that I will
> still receive it

Yes you will still receive the emails from people, so the situation here is that they have not responded.

Comment: Agree with John. The email received will not be affected by automatic reply. All emails sent to you by others will be received normally.

Comment: Just checking if your problem has been resolved. If you think John reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer.